# Handling Null exception when my Object is still empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I handle this null exception?

I have a button that dequeues the data from my static variable class

```
public ActionResult BtnNext()
{
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        var first = MyQueue.todayQueue.Dequeue();
        MyQueue.todayQueue.Count();
        ViewBag.QueueItem = first;
        return View();
}
```

And here is my view, this shows the data that I dequeued.

```
@{
    var item = (Rosh.QueueMe.Web.Models.MyQueue)ViewBag.QueueItem;
}

@{
    if (item != null)
    {
        //Help here.
    }
}


   <p>@item.QueueNumber</p>
```

I still don't know how to handle when my viewbag is still empty / null.
Right now I get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. / item was null.

The code won't proceed to my index page since it is null.

Comment: Your `item != null` check is in one code block, but you are referencing it directly later on (`@item.QueueNumber`).

Comment: `if(ViewBag.QueueItem != null)` safeguard condition before casting or use `as` operator

Comment: @BrendanGreen what do you mean?

Comment: You have a check if `item != null`, and then further below you output `item.QueueNumber` **without** checking if `item` is null or not.  Wrap the output in an `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to check for `null` for `ViewBag.QueueItem` as well or use `as` for reference casting which takes care in case of `ViewBag.QueueItem` is not being set or is `null`. So you can adjust it like:

```
@{
    var item = ViewBag.QueueItem as Rosh.QueueMe.Web.Models.MyQueue;
}
```

now the `item` will be set to `null` in case of `ViewBag.QueueItem` is `null`

Comment: its still say item was null

Comment: the error is in my `<p>@item.QueueNumber</p>`

Comment: You need to wrap that output in an `if` block that checks if `item` is null or not.

Comment: or use null coleasing : `<p>@item?.QueueNumber</p>`

Comment: can u provide me the proper code? im just a newbie